# pjsip call hangup delayed if network switches from IPv6 to IPv4 during call

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

I am using `PJSIP` client for handling `VOIP` calls.currently I have two servers setup.

**1 - test1.myvoipserver.com (only support IPv4)**

**2 - test2.myvoipserver.com (only support IPv6)**

In the client-side, I am checking if user IP belongs to `IPv4` family than I am routing the call from test1.myvoipserver.com server which is supporting `IPv4`.

If user IP belongs to `IPv6` family, I am routing the call from test2.myvoipserver.com which is supporting only `IPv6`.

All calls are working fine except the below scenario.

**Scenario:**

Let’s suppose user has two internet connections available.

4G - (Only on IPv6)

Wifi - (Only on IPv4)

The user has made a call on 4G, call was accepted by Party B and media packets are traveling fine. During the call, the user has started moving where Wifi is available his mobile internet automatically switches to Wifi. At that moment media packets will be lost which is understandable. I want to disconnect the current call and made a new call again with the `IPv4` server as Wifi is on `IPv4`.

**Actual Result **: On internet changes from `IPv6` to `IPv4` I forcefully disconnecting current call but the call is not disconnected immediately on party A and B, it will be disconnected after 2 minutes (probably when pjsip/server sends timeout).

**Expected Result** : Call should be disconnected immediately on both party A and party B

**My Understanding** : As my current call was on `IPv6` server but new IP my device getting belongs to `IPv4` and my current call server does not support `IPv4` address so that’s why When sending Bye from client, server is not sending OK/ACK.

**Note : Facing this issue is on `PSTN` Calls.**